# Is it possible to 'exclude from view layer' all hierarchy?

Tags: viewlayers

I have lots of collections inside collections. Somehow some of them got 'excluded from view layer' (the small box unticked). I would expect Shift-LMB to exclude/include all children collections (like with visibility) but it does not. Now I have to do this manually for each child, one by one. Is there a way to achieve this with one click?

[image]

Comment: Just exclude the mother collection. Did I missunderstand the question?

Comment: That would work if I only wanted to `exclude` the hierarchy. My problem is the other way round; somehow some of the collections inside were excluded, and just ticking the box of the main collection does not enable the children collections too. I want to re-include all children collections, everything inside, with one click

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem you have. I tested it with 3.4.1 and 3.2.2...

Comment: @radoo I have version 3.4.1 and here's the way to reproduce the problem: exclude child collections from view layer. If you do this while the mother collection is not excluded, toggling the setting for the mother collection back and forth doesn't change the setting for the child collections.

Comment: Did you try shift-click?